# In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned

Tags: android

I am new in developing app using In-app billing,I had implmented it but some
times its giving me the following error
 In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned
give me solution on it

Comment: I hate those "expert" who always down vote other's post. So I up vote for you although you question is not complete. But I think anybody who encountered this should understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consume an item before buying it again..

```
IabHelper mHelper = new IabHelper(ACTIVITY, base64EncodedPublicKey);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

Comment: mHelper.consumeAsync(YOUR SKU, finishListener);

Comment: please explain me in detail

Comment: If you have implemented the consumption call before then you havent overidden the onActivityResult Mehtod in your acitvity.

I have made edit to my answer please check.

Comment: and since you have called buy and havent called consume.. You have to call consume explicitly first on that sku inorder for it to be available to buy again..

Comment: i tried with onactivityresult but still its not working...giving the same error

Comment: did you call consume before you called purchase again?

Comment: yes..i had but still not..can i share code with you??

Comment: of course. please edit the question and let me know in the comment.

Comment: hello farooq..cant edit question..its bigger module..its giving error of IBtabhelper..while formating the code..so can i mail you?

Answer (score 1):

As an example project given in [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)
Named TrivialDrive we can consume purchased item as follow...

```
    // Check for gas delivery -- if we own gas, we should fill up the tank immediately
    Purchase gasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS);
    if (gasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(gasPurchase)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "We have gas. Consuming it.");
        mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS), mConsumeFinishedListener);
        return;
    }

// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we consume,
        // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than one
        // sku, you probably should check...
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in our
            // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas tank a bit
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
            mTank = mTank == TANK_MAX ? TANK_MAX : mTank + 1;
            saveData();
            alert("You filled 1/4 tank. Your tank is now " + String.valueOf(mTank) + "/4 full!");
        }
        else {
            complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        updateUi();
        setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};
```

Hope!!! It help You. You can  go through this example project.

Comment: Do you know about Unable to buy error 5- Developer error >

Comment: RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5 - invalid arguments provided to the API       you can check this in given IInAppBillingService.aidl